# JPA sequence generator generates unexpected ID

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When I am trying to create entity

```
getEntityManager().persist(entity);
```

I have exception below

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pkproperty"
  Detail: Key (id)=(191375) already exists.
```

I cannot understand whence it takes this value of ID. I have just one sequence in my database and its value was 191418 before I execute entity creation.

This entity's ID description is

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_id")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
```

And in database I have already created sequence `seq_id`

Is there any default sequence that can be used? If yes than how can I check it's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence allocation set in JPA must match the allocation size used in the database or you will get a mismatch during allocation.  Try specifying the allocationSize=1 in the SequenceGenerator definition:

@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_id", allocationSize=1)

Comment: `@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "InvSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "InvSeq", sequenceName = "seq_id", allocationSize = 1)`
i've tried like this. it doesn't help

Comment: Turn on logging then to see what statements are issued.  191418 is 43 off from the 191375 being used, which to me points to the default allocation size of 50 being used and not the 1 you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing without sequence, refer below code. your pk column should be auto increment and auto increment should start from 191418.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Long id;
```

Comment: maybe it can be alternative way, but it doesn't answer to my question.